# Jquery Filtering Table results on data attribute

Tags: jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute

I have a simple table that shows date in columns. Each `<td>` has a data attribute `data-port` I'd like to filter the results shown in the table, based on an option selected from a drop downlist.

The HTML is :

```
<select id='filter'>
<option></option>
<option value='fd18'>OPTION A</option>
<option value='af13'>OPTION B</option>
</select>

<table id='table1'>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="123" class="title">123</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="456" class="title">456</div></td>
    <td data-port="0000"><div id="789" class="title">789</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="213" class="title">213</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="345" class="title">345</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="946" class="title">946</div></td>
    <td data-port="0000"><div id="368" class="title">368</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="246" class="title">246</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="642" class="title">642</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="759" class="title">795</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="335" class="title">335</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="556" class="title">556</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using jquery I'm trying to show the td's where the data-port equals the selected option and hide the rest. How can I do this and it is it possible to dynamically update the table layout so I still end up with neat columns.

The jquery I'm using is :

```
$('#filter').change(function() {
    var port = $(this).val()
    console.log( port )
    $("td > [data-port!=" + port+ "]").hide();
    $("td > [data-port=" + port+ "]").show();
});
```

The console shows the correct value being returned, but I end up hiding all TD's on the page not just the ones which don't match

Any ideas how I can do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for:

```js
$('#filter').change(function() {
    var port = $(this).val()
    console.log( port )
    if ( port !== '' ) {
      $("td[data-port!=" + port+ "]").css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $("td[data-port=" + port+ "]").css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
      $("td").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='filter'>
<option value=''></option>
<option value='fd18'>OPTION A</option>
<option value='af13'>OPTION B</option>
</select>

<table id='table1'>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="123" class="title">123</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="456" class="title">456</div></td>
    <td data-port="0000"><div id="789" class="title">789</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="213" class="title">213</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="345" class="title">345</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="946" class="title">946</div></td>
    <td data-port="0000"><div id="368" class="title">368</div></td>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="246" class="title">246</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td data-port="af13"><div id="642" class="title">642</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="759" class="title">795</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="335" class="title">335</div></td>
    <td data-port="fd18"><div id="556" class="title">556</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You have the arrow sign after your TD in your jQuery code.
That means, first child **after** TD that is having data-port attr.
In your case, your TD has the data-port attr self.

Comment: I get an error when I try and run that snippet. "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9

Comment: That is true, you need jQuery lib. Edited the snippet, you are good to go :)

Comment: Thanks that helps. Is there any way to tidy the page formatting ? Selecting option A results in one entry on the second row by it's self.

Comment: Check snippet again. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was hoping to move all the cells so they appeared in order without any gaps in any rows etc. But I'm happy with how this is. Thanks